# Superclass for template <int v> class Foo

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, superclass

Suppose that I have a template class

```
template <int v>
class Foo {...}
```

I have a function

```
void f(...)
```

that accept as inputs any object of Foo<1>, Foo<2> etc, how can I define the function? It seems that

```
void f(Foo x)
```

does not compile. What is a common type for Foo<1>, Foo<100>, ... and all Foo?

Comment: There is no superclass to `template <int v> class Foo`, each `Foo<1>`, `Foo<2>`, `Foo<3>` is like an own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is a common type for Foo<1>, Foo<100>, ... and all Foo?

There is no common type.  What you can do though is make `f` a template as well

```
template <int v>
void f(Foo<v> x)
{
    //code here
}
```

like above and now the function will accept any `Foo` you give it.

Comment: Is Foo <> a common type? Just ask.

Comment: @zell `Foo <>` is not a type.  Templates are **not a type**.  A template is a recipe, and once your code is compiled, wont even exist in the binary.

Comment: Nitpick: in this example `Foo <>` isn't a template or a type, it's ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make `f` a template too:

```cpp
template <int v>
void foo(Foo<v> x)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other already pointed out you can use your existing definition of Foo and use a template function foo.

If you really want a common type for all instantiations of your Foo template you have to add it as a base class of Foo.

```
class FooBase {...};

template<int v>
class Foo : public FooBase {...};
```

Then you can write a foo function which accepts a pointer or reference to the base class. But this makes only sence if you add some virtual function to your base class which you override in the Foo template class:

```
#include<iostream>

class FooBase {
  public:
    virtual int doubleIt() const = 0;
};

template<int v>
class Foo : public FooBase {
  public:
   int doubleIt() const {return 2*v;}
};

void foo(FooBase* x) {
  int d = x->doubleIt();
  std::cout << "x->double() is " << d << std::endl;
  // do stuff with d
}

int main() {
    Foo<2> a;
    foo(&a);

    Foo<3> b;
    foo(&b);
}
```

[Demo Code](https://godbolt.org/z/MXij_d)